# Using Pandas groupby how can you aggregate a column of lists using addition?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with a column that contains a list of values.  Each row in the dataframe has a list of the same length.  I'd like to use Dataframe.groupby to group the data in the dataframe and sum together the lists in the following fashion:

In:

```
import pandas as pd

#Sample data
a = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'test', list([0,1,2,3,4])],['b', 'test', list([5,6,7,8,9])]], columns=['id', 'grp', 'values'])
print(a)

#Some function to group the dataframe
#b = a.groupby('grp').someAggregationFunction()

#Example of desired output
b = pd.DataFrame([['test', list([5,7,9,11,13])]], columns=['grp', 'values'])
    print(b)
```

Out:

```
  id   grp           values
0  a  test  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1  b  test  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    grp             values
0  test  [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push it into one line

```
a.groupby('grp')['values'].apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame(x.values.tolist()).sum().tolist())
Out[286]: 
grp
test    [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
Name: values, dtype: object
```

Also I recommend do not using `apply` here

```
b=pd.DataFrame(a['values'].values.tolist()).groupby(a['grp']).sum()
pd.DataFrame({'grp':b.index,'values':b.values.tolist()})
Out[293]: 
    grp             values
0  test  [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Comment: Understand the performance implications of apply, however for my actual implementation it was the best fit.  Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 3):

You may not like this answer, but it's better not to use lists in dataframes. You should seek, wherever possible, to use numeric series for numeric data:

```
res = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('values').tolist()))\
        .groupby('grp').sum().reset_index()

print(res)

    grp  0  1  2   3   4
0  test  5  7  9  11  13
```

Comment: that is what I will recommended :-) Nice dude

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to `transform` your `lists` into `np.arrays` and use simple sum

```
a['v'] = a.v.transform(np.array)
a.groupby('grp').v.apply(lambda x: x.sum())

    grp     v
0   test    [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Notice that I changed `values` to `v` not to be mistaken with the `.values` accessor from `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

Using `numpy.stack`:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    [(i, np.stack(g).sum(0)) for i, g in a.groupby('grp')['values']],
    columns=['grp', 'values']
)
```

```
    grp             values
0  test  [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

Also using `apply`, but `apply` will be slow:

```
a.groupby('grp')['values'].apply(lambda x: np.stack(x).sum(0)).to_frame('values')
```

```
                 values
grp
test  [5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```